# Excel VBA - Copy a formula result to a cell in another sheet + add succesive formula results in consecutive rows each time the formula is recalculated

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am running a partially randomize set of data and trying to find the best solutions depending on certain parameter changes. I need to "record" certain solutions and then compare different results for different parameters each time the randomized variables are recalculated.

I would like to do the to following:

1. On Sheet1, cell S255, is the result of a formula =SUM(M252:S252)
2. I need to automatically add that result (Sheet1 S255), to Sheet5, column A, starting at A1.
3. Then, each time the formula is recalculated and the result changes, I need the new result to be added to the consecutive row to the previous result (so the second result would go to A2, third one to A3, and so on).

Looking for similar cases I have come to be able to do #1 and #2 using this event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet5") 'declare and set the worksheet the data is to be copied into, amend the sheet name as required
If Target.Address = "$S$255" Then 'if anything changes in C6 or C9 in this sheet
   ws.Range("A1").Value = Target.Parent.Range("S255") 'copy the value from cell C10 in this sheet to Sheet2 in cell E5
End If
End Sub
```

Doing #3 is proving more challenging. What event would be suitable to do so?

Thanks in advance for your time and understanding!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Option Explicit
```

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

```
Dim newValue As Range
Set newValue = Range("S255")
Dim oldValue As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = Sheet5
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheet1
    
    With ws1
        x = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        oldValue = .Cells(x, 1).Value
        x = x + 1
        If oldValue <> newValue Then .Cells(x, 1) = newValue
    End With
```

End Sub

It runs on the worksheet_calculate event but only inserts the new value if the value has changed from the previous calculation. It starts at A2, so you can put a heading in A1 or do a test for a value if you really want to start in A1.

HTH
Justin